# Defining a tree + a pointer to its subtree in ocaml

Tags: list, pointers, tree, constants, ocaml

How to define a tree + a pointer to its subtree in OCaml such that adding leaves in this subtree takes constant time?

Comment: In the pure subset of OCaml, data is immutable.  So you can't add leaves to a tree.  You can only make a new tree that's similar to the old tree but with extra leaves.  If you use OCaml's impure constructs, the solution is going to look pretty much as in any imperative language.  Can you show what code you've tried so far?

Comment: In the impure subset of OCaml, data is mutable. You can mutate records, strings, records, so what you are looking for is indeed possible in OCaml, and not in a pure language.

Comment: @Jeffrey: What I've done is just adding leaves by walking down the path, so something like,  
`type tree = Empty | Node of 'a * tree list
let rec add a path = function
  | Empty -> Node (a, [])
  | Node(s, c) -> 
    if (empty path) then Node(s, Node(a, [])::c) else
      Node(s, List.map (fun x -> if (greater_than path (path_to x)) then add a (substract path (path_to x)) else x) c)`  
However, the path that I used will getting longer in the next step of building the tree, so having like a pointer will be handy.Maybe I will try out some suggestion here, zipper or mutable records.

Comment: Would balancing the tree help? A zipper isn't going to have a great complexity if the nodes are added all over the place and the context has to move across the entire tree.

Comment: No, I cannot use balancing tree, I kind of need to preserve the structure of the tree. But yes I could use a zipper. I'm wondering how to extend that in general case, since every nodes may have different number of successors, and I'm using a list to denote the set of children

Comment: You might have to split the list, where the context is your current location, and a next node, with the path the reverse list of nodes you've visited and the actual path to the root and rest of the tree.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use purely functional representation, zippers -- suggested by nlucaroni -- are indeed the good solution to represent a cursor deep down a data structure, that can be moved or used to update the structure.

If you wish for a solution using in-place mutation, you can use mutable data through `mutable` record fields, or the references (`ref`) that are derived from it. For example:

```
type 'a tree_cell = {mutable node : 'a tree}
and 'a tree = Leaf of 'a | Branch of 'a tree_cell * 'a * 'a tree_cell
```

If you hold an `'a tree_cell`, you can mutate it (in constant time).

```
let head {node = (Leaf x | Branch(_, x, _))} = x

let duplicate cell =
  cell.node <- Branch (cell, head cell, {node = cell.node})
```

**Edit:** in the comments of your question, you seem to indicate your interest in a solution for n-ary trees.

The general n-ary case can be represented as

```
type 'a tree_cell = {mutable node: 'a tree}
and 'a tree = Branch of 'a * 'a tree_cell list
```

while the zipper solution would look like (untested code)

```
type 'a tree = Branch of 'a * 'a forest
and 'a forest = 'a tree list

(* the data between the current cursor and the root of the tree *)
type 'a top_context = Top | Under of 'a * 'a tree * 'a top_context

(* a cursor on the 'data' element of a tree *)
type 'a data_cursor = top_context * 'a tree list

(* plug some data in the hole and get a tree back *)
val fill_data : 'a data_cursor -> 'a -> 'a tree

(* a cursor on one of the children of a tree *)
type 'a list_zipper = 'a list * 'a list
type 'a children_cursor = top_context * 'a * 'a tree list_zipper

(* plug some subtree in the hole and get a tree back *)
val fill_children : 'a children_cursor -> 'a tree -> 'a tree

(* carve a data hole at the root; also return what was in the hole *)
val top_data : 'a tree -> 'a data_cursor * 'a

(* fill a data hole and get a cursor for the first children in return
   -- if it exists *)
val move_down : 'a data_cursor -> 'a -> ('a children_cursor * 'a tree) option
(* fill the children hole and carve out the one on the left *)
val move_left : 'a data_cursor -> 'a tree -> ('a data_cursor * 'a tree) option
val move_right : 'a data_cursor -> 'a tree -> ('a data_cursor * 'a tree) option
(* fill the children hole and get a cursor on the data *)
val move_up : 'a children_cursor -> 'a tree -> 'a data_cursor * 'a
```

Answer (score 4):

Another (simpler and more general) solution for a binary tree:

```
type 'a t = {
  value : 'a;
  mutable left : 'a t option;
  mutable right : 'a t option;
}
```

With this type, you can set independently the left and right subtree as they become needed.